# How to apply mix colors in curves?

Tags: uv, bezier-curves, color, color-management

I want to apply colors on the spherical curve (shown below):

[image]

But I want it to be colored as below:
[image]

I am so tired of finding the solutions on you tube but did not find the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Cycles, you can obtain this on a curve:

[image]

The material node setup is the following:

[image]
1- From texture coordinate input node use UV

2- Separate the UV coordinates

3- Keep the 'U' (= X) coordinate and set it as input in a color ramp (add the wanted colors to it)

4/5- Set the result in your shader

Finally, go to the curve properties and set the texture space to use 'UV for mapping'. 'U' (=X) is along the curve and 'V' (=Y) is transversal to the curve.

[image]

Comment: I see in my blender 2.69 "Seperate RGB" instead of "Seperate XYZ" is this option not available in 2.69?

Comment: @PrashantTomar, I don't remember. It is normally in the 'converters'. 'Separate XYZ' is more logical here, but that should work with 'separate RGB' too (I confirm here in 2.78)